# Animate elements in order in CSS

Tags: html, css

I was somehow playing with how articles are appearing…

And I was thinking about doing something like that so that each paragraph appears after the previous ones:

```css
div p {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

p:nth-of-type(1) {
  transition-delay: 0.5s;
}

p:nth-of-type(2) {
  transition-delay: 1.0s;
}

p:nth-of-type(3) {
  transition-delay: 1.5s;
}

p:nth-of-type(4) {
  transition-delay: 2.0s;
}

div:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover below:</p>
<div>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

This tiny snippet works “nicely” but…

How can it be done easily, only with native CSS, so that it manages correctly a text with - let's say - a hundred paragraphs?

---

⋅
⋅
⋅

Here is my current "article layout".

I asked here because I was trying to optimize it!

```css
table p {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}

table img {
  transform: rotateY(90deg);
  transition: transform 1s ease;
}

tr:nth-of-type(1) p {
  transition-delay: 1.0s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(2) img {
  transition-delay: 1.25s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(3) img {
  transition-delay: 1.5s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(4) img {
  transition-delay: 1.75s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(2) p {
  transition-delay: 2.0s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(2) img {
  transition-delay: 2.25s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(3) img {
  transition-delay: 2.5s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-of-type(4) img {
  transition-delay: 2.75s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(3) p {
  transition-delay: 3.0s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2) img {
  transition-delay: 3.25s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(3) img {
  transition-delay: 3.5s;
}

tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(4) img {
  transition-delay: 3.75s;
}

table:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}

table:hover img {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
```

```html
<p>Hover below:</p>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Content</p>
    </td>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/86/54"></td>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/86/55"></td>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/86/56"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Content</p>
    </td>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/88/54"></td>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/88/55"></td>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/88/56"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p>Content</p>
    </td>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/90/54"></td>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/90/55"></td>
    <td><img src="http://placekitten.com/90/56"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, ofcourse this is done more easily with jQuery but thats out of the question...

Comment: Basically... **you can't**. CSS isn't dynamic or incremental like that.

Comment: @MartijnVissers, Yep. JavaScript would be enough, too.

Comment: for js/jquery.. show my answer

Comment: @לבנימלכה I know how to do it with JS or jQuery. That's why I precisely asked for “native CSS”. And you precisely did all the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate this using a layer above the elements that you animate in order to show them one by one:

```css
div.box {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
div.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:1;
  top:-200%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent ,#fff 75%);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  background-position:bottom;
  transition:background-size 2s,transform 0s 2s;
  transform-origin:0 83.25%;
}
div.box:hover::before {
  background-size:100% 0%;
  transform:scaleY(-1);
}
```

```html
<p>Hover below:</p>
<div class="box">
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Temani! That's what I would have done at the beginning… but that doesn't work with my other animations (in my case the apparition of images).

Comment: @TakitIsy yes but there is no CSS way to have what you want, we can only approximate it .. probably if you show your example with images we can find another trick

Comment: I'll add another snippet to show my perticular case. I'll tell you.

Comment: Here it is, my new snippet!

Comment: @TakitIsy I see, it's a bit complex .. Will try to find an idea